# Дан текстовый файл. Необходимо переписать его строки в другой файл. Си

Tags: c, строки, файлы, текст

Дан текстовый файл. Необходимо переписать его строки в другой файл. Порядок строк во втором файле должен быть обратным по отношению к порядку строк в заданном файле.

Вот мой код: (Что в нем не так, прога вылетает)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincon.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    FILE *read, *copy;
    int count = 0;                //для подсчета кол-ва строк в массиве
    int i = 0;                    //для обращения в ячейку массива
    char buf[300];              //для хранения строки
    char **mas;                 //основной рабочий массив

    if ((fopen_s(&read, "read.txt", "r")) != 0)
    {
        printf("Невозможно открыть файл.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((fopen_s(&copy, "copy.txt", "w+")) != 0) {
        printf("Невозможно открыть файл.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (!feof(read))
    {
        fgets(buf, 300, read);
        count++;
    }
    fclose(read);

    cout << count << endl;
    //---------------------------------------создаем динамический массив и копируем в него строки----------------

    mas = new char*[count];

    if (fopen_s(&read, "read.txt", "r"))
    {
        while (!feof(read))
        {
            fgets(buf, 300, read);
            mas[i] = new char[strlen(buf)+1];
            strcpy_s(mas[i], 300, buf);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(read);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
        cout << mas[i] << endl;

    //------------------------------из массива копируем в новый файл в обратном порядке---------------------------

    if (copy)
    {
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            fputs(mas[i], copy);
            if (i == count - 1)
                fputs("\n", copy);
        }
        fclose(copy);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
        delete[]mas[i];
    delete[]mas;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` - это уже никак не C :)

Comment: для начала: а вы уверены, что выделяете достаточно памяти под массив? а то у вас количество строк вводится почему-то с клавиатуры, а размер буфера строго ограничен. и что значит "вылетает"? код компилируется?

Comment: strcpy_s(mas[i], 300, buf); - на этой строке выдает ошибку "прекращена робота программы" и закрывает консоль.

Comment: я повтарюсь: а вы точно уверены, что выделили достаточно памяти? этот ваш mas[i] - вообще существует?

Comment: Вроде, count у меня равно  4. Значит mas[i] существует

Comment: так а `i` у вас вот это точно в пределах от 0 до 3 включительно? Потому что мне ваш ответ говорит ниочем! Ну вы бы еще сказали: у меня сегодня дождь, так что `i` точно в нужных пределах...

Comment: В строке `strcpy_s(mas[i], 300, buf);` второй параметр неверный. Размер буфера, выделенного для `mas[i]` вовсе не 300. Ну и верность самого индекса `i` тоже вызывает сомнения.

Comment: i = 0, к  i++ компилятор не доходит. Так вылетает на mas[i] = new char[strlen(buf)+1];

Answer (score 2):

Вариант, который не требует скачивания исходного файла в память.

Идея состоит в том, что на самом деле мы можем сдвигаться (см. [fseek](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek)) перед записью в файл в любое его место и писать очередную строку туда. Поэтому будем записывать строки в выходной файл сзади наперед, продвигаясь от его конца к началу.

Измерим размер исходного файла. Прочтем первую строку из него. Отступим в выходном файле назад  от размера входного файла на длину прочитанной строки и запишем ее. Далее повторяем, отступая назад от позиции начала последней выведенной строки.

Впрочем, лучше посмотрите на сам код -)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  if ( 3 != argc )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./a.out in-file out-reverse-file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  FILE *fp_in = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
  if ( NULL == fp_in ) return -2;

  FILE *fp_out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
  if ( NULL == fp_out ) return -2;

  if ( fseek( fp_in, 0, SEEK_END ) ) return -3; 
  long int outpos = ftell( fp_in ); /*теперь в outpos находится размер файла*/
  if ( fseek( fp_in, 0, SEEK_SET ) ) return -3;

  /*здесь будет размер прочитанной строчки*/
  ssize_t line_size;

  /*сюда будет записываться сама строка*/
  char* line = NULL;  

  /*здесь будет размер для line, динамически выделенной 
  функцией getline (потому что line у нас NULL)*/
  size_t strcap;      

  while ( ( line_size = getline( &line, &strcap, fp_in ) ) > 0) 
  {
    outpos -= line_size;
    if ( fseek( fp_out, outpos, SEEK_SET ) != 0 || fputs( line, fp_out ) == EOF )
      return -4;
  }

  /*не забываем освободить память, 
  динамически выделенной функцией getline*/
  free(line);

  return 0;
}
```

Если же в вашей системе отсутствует [getline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), то ее написание будет в любом смысле полезным упражнением.

Comment: Что это за троллинг? Может, код перевернёте? Или так было задумано? :D

Comment: @GromovAnton, конечно задумано (для людей, у которых комп чувство юмора еще не отбил -)) (но если настаиваете, могу и перевернуть)

Comment: я только что разобрал код : я счастлив, что извиняюсь и в одно и то же время благодарю за столь лаконичное решение (не учитывая портящих зрение exit-ов, rewind'а, за которым не уследишь, успешно ли он был завершён, и сам getline, но , к счастью, это не так проблематично). Я вам рассказывал правду про свой случай, но не до конца понял, как вы конкретно записываете, и не думал, что можно файловый поток сместить заранее, ничего туда ещё не записывая. Это просто гениально. Ещё раз благодарю вас : "открыли" мне глаза :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file in> <file out>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fin, *fout;

    if ((fin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    if ((fout = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        perror(argv[2]);
        return 3;
    }

    size_t lines = 0;
    while (!feof(fin))
    {
        int k = fgetc(fin);
        if (k == '\n')
            lines++;
    }

    char buffer[256];
    char **a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * lines);
    assert(a);
    fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    size_t i = 0;
    while (!feof(fin))
    {
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fin) != NULL)
        {
            size_t len = strlen(buffer);
            a[i] = malloc(len + 1);
            assert(a[i]);
            memcpy(a[i], buffer, len + 1);
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (long i = lines - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        fprintf(fout, "%s", a[i]);
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проверять feof **до чтения** неправильно. Читайте и проверяйте результат  -- `while(fgets(...)) { ...`, `while((k = fgetc(f)) != EOF) ...` и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

### Пролог:

У @avp решение гораздо лучше, но если вам по каким-то причинам нужны какие-то более сложные посреднические манипуляции с текстом, записав их,например, в `char**`, то можете посмотреть моё решение.

---

Нету функций, всё в одном, поэтому не можете сами разобраться.

Давайте-ка я просто напишу это на ANSI-стандарте :)

### Несколько заметок:

- комментариев мало, потому что это было бы избыточно :D ;
- старался всё тщательно валидировать, поэтому код кажется большим ;
- директивы препроцессора  - в конце.

Сам `main` :

```
/*gcc -o main ...*/
/*./main input_file output_file*/
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if ( 3 != argc ) return -1;
    if ( 0 != write_reverse_from( argv[1], argv[2] ) )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Writing has been failed!\n");
        return -2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Всё самое интересное находится в `write_reverse_from` (старался писать максимально ,в моём понимании, "чисто", чтобы вам было понятно) :

```
int write_reverse_from ( const char* file_in_name, const char* file_out_name )
{
    FILE* fp_input;
    FILE* fp_output;

    char** input_content;
    uint32_t lines_count;
    char** output_content;

    fp_input = fopen( file_in_name, "r" );
    fp_output = fopen( file_out_name, "w" );

    if ( NULL == fp_input ) return -1;
    if ( NULL == fp_output ) return -2;

    /*получить количество строк в файле*/
    lines_count = get_lines_count_from( fp_input ); 
    if ( 0 == lines_count ) return -3;

    /*получить контент в виде массива строк*/
    input_content = get_input_content( fp_input, lines_count ); 

    /*закрываем файловый поток исходного файла. Больше не нужен*/
    fclose( fp_input ); 

    if ( NULL == input_content ) 
    {
        fclose( fp_output );
        return -4;
    }

    /*получить "перевёрнутый" массив строк*/
    output_content = get_reversed_content_from( input_content, lines_count ); 
    if ( NULL == output_content )
    { 
        free_content( input_content, lines_count ); 
        fclose( fp_output );
        return -5;       
    }

    /*записать результат в итоговый файл*/
    print_content_to( fp_output, output_content, lines_count ); 

    /*динамическое освобождение памяти content-ов*/
    free_content( input_content, lines_count );
    free_content( output_content, lines_count );
    fclose( fp_output );
    return 0;
}
```

Показываю сейчас реализации по порядку.

Функция `get_lines_count_from` просто "пробегается" стандартным способом (не `feof`-ным, прошу заметить :D) по файлу, "накручивая" простой счётчик :

```
static uint32_t get_lines_count_from ( FILE* opened_fp )
{
    uint32_t lines_count = 0L;
    char line[ MAX_LINE_SIZE ];

    if ( NULL == opened_fp ) return 0;

    fseek( opened_fp, 0L, SEEK_SET );

    /* решения с feof лучше не использовать */
    while ( NULL != fgets( line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, opened_fp ) ) 
        lines_count++;

    return lines_count;
}
```

Вот как я беру содержимое входного файла :

```
static char** get_input_content ( FILE* opened_fp, uint32_t lines_count )
{
    char line[ MAX_LINE_SIZE ] = {0};
    char** content;
    uint32_t alloc_counter = 0L;

    if ( NULL == opened_fp || 0L == lines_count ) return NULL;

    content = malloc( sizeof( char** ) * lines_count );
    while( alloc_counter < lines_count )
    {
        content[alloc_counter] = malloc( sizeof(char*) * MAX_LINE_SIZE );
        alloc_counter++;
    }

    alloc_counter = 0L;
    fseek( opened_fp, 0L, SEEK_SET );
    while( NULL != fgets( line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, opened_fp ) )
    {
        strcpy( content[alloc_counter], line );
        memset( line, 0, MAX_LINE_SIZE);
        alloc_counter++;
    }

    return content;
}
```

Вот оно самое "переворачивание" :

```
static char** get_reversed_content_from( char** content, uint32_t lines_count )
{
    uint32_t alloc_counter = 0L;
    char* last_content_line;
    char** reversed_content;

    if ( NULL == content || 0L == lines_count ) return NULL;

    last_content_line = content[ lines_count - 1UL ];
    if ( NULL == strchr( last_content_line, '\n' ) ) /*если в последней строке нет символа новой строки*/
    {
        if ( MAX_LINE_SIZE - 1UL <= strlen( last_content_line ) ) return NULL;
        strcat( last_content_line, LINE_END );
        /*символ NUL после этого добавлять не обязательно, потому что
        при чтении у нас ифнормация заносилась в заранее инициализированный нулями
        массив, и только потом было перемещение в динамическую память (найдите строчку с memset)*/
    }

    reversed_content = malloc( sizeof( char** ) * lines_count );
    while( alloc_counter < lines_count )
    {
        reversed_content[alloc_counter] = malloc( sizeof(char*) * MAX_LINE_SIZE );
        strcpy(reversed_content[alloc_counter], content[lines_count - 1U - alloc_counter]);
        alloc_counter++;
    }

    return reversed_content;
}
```

Вывод в итоговый файл :

```
static int print_content_to( FILE* opened_fp, char** content, uint32_t lines_count)
{
    uint32_t lines_counter = 0;
    if ( NULL == opened_fp || NULL == content || 0L == lines_count ) return -1;

    while( lines_counter < lines_count )
    {
        fprintf(opened_fp, "%s", content[lines_counter]);
        lines_counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Само освобождение переменных типа`char**` :

```
static void free_content( char** content, uint32_t lines_count)
{
    uint32_t lines_counter = 0;

    if ( NULL == content || 0 == lines_count ) return;

    while ( lines_counter < lines_count )
    {
        free(content[lines_counter]);
        lines_counter++;
    }

    free(content);
}
```

Ну и обещанные директивы :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE ( 1024UL )

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define LINE_END "\r\n"
#else
    #define LINE_END "\n"
#endif
```

Comment: А зачем полностью копировать в память исходный файл?

Comment: @avp , как, по-вашему, я мог сделать по-другому? "Залил" данные файла в память -> сделал изменения -> залил в назначенный файл.  Короче способов я не придумал. Если вы намекаете на то, что при считывании одной строчки исходного файла её можно сразу вписывать в начало конечного файла, то вы ошибаетесь, потому что каждый раз эта строчка будет перезаписываться, и в итоге в конечном файле будет только одна строка : последняя строка исходного файла. Если вы знаете, как сделать это лучше, то , пожалуйста, напишите :)

Comment: @avp , только сейчас понял, про что вы. Убрал аргумент "rb", тестил кое-что с ним, вот и забыл :) А вообще - винде и Linux'у пофигу : всё равно читают, как надо :D

Comment: Не, я именно о том, что совсем не обязательно читать все строки в память для того, чтобы сделать файл с ними в обратном порядке. Можно сначала посмотреть размер входного файла и тут же сделать выходной *того же размера* (системный вызов `ftruncate`). Затем читаем построчно входной файл и тут же пишем строку в выходной, смещаясь на нужное расстояние от его конца (или текущей позиции в нем (это уж как вам считать удобней -))).

Comment: @avp Во-первых, системный вызов - это некроссплатформенное решение.Во-вторых, как вы собираетесь считывать и выводить строку за 1 итерацию? Вы попробуйте сами на досуге так сделать, а потом вернётесь к моим ранним словам : если я запишу строку в выходной файл, а на сл. итерации попытаюсь в эту строку "впихнуть" что-то в начало (а нам, по сути, так и надо, если мы решили пойти таким путём), то информация **перезапишется**, а не допишется в это начало (я тоже так пытался сделать, поэтому и сообщаю, что за один подход в виде "прочитал строку - вывел строку" для такой задачи не подходит) :)

Comment: @avp единственное, что я тут мог бы оптимизировать, то это узнать размер файла (не вашим способом, а [этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)), а потом динамически создать строку в размере этого файла вместо матрицы, но видимость и простота для меня - это первым делом :D

Comment: Ну, можно и кроссплатформенно, просто fseek-ом (и что вас всех так на кроссплатформенность тянет?). Впрочем, просто посмотрите код в моем ответе (предчувствуя, сподобился накрапать чуток -)) (естественно, он перевернут собой же)